# Euclidean propagator expression for massless particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, integration, greens-functions, propagator

Let $\Delta_F(\tilde{x})$ denote the Feynman propagator in the Euclidean variable $\tilde{x}$, in $D$ dimensions,
$$\Delta_F(\tilde{x}) = \int \frac{\text{d}^D\tilde{p}}{(2\pi)^D}\frac{e^{i\,\tilde{p}\cdot\tilde{x}}}{\tilde{p}^2+m^2}.\tag{1}$$

Since this expression is $\mathrm{O}(D)$ invariant, one can change variables to spherical coordinates and simplify the expression, yielding
$$\Delta_F(\tilde{x}) = \frac{S_{D-2}}{(2\pi)^D}\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi} \text{d}\tilde{p}\text{d}\theta\,\frac{\tilde{p}^{D-1}}{\tilde{p}^2+m^2}e^{i\,\tilde{p}\cdot\tilde{x}}\, \left(\sin(\theta)\right)^{D-2}.\tag{2}$$

For $m = 0$,
$$\Delta_F(\tilde{x}) = \frac{S_{D-2}}{(2\pi)^D}\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi} \text{d}\tilde{p}\text{d}\theta\,\tilde{p}^{D-3}\, \left(\sin(\theta)\right)^{D-2}e^{i\,|\tilde{p}||\tilde{x}|\cos(\theta)}.\tag{3}$$

However, I am supposed to get
$$\Delta_F(\tilde{x}) = \frac{1}{(D-2)S_{D-1}}\frac{1}{r^{D-2}}.\tag{4}$$

Any ideas on how one can proceed further?

Edit: Had forgotten to add some extra steps.

Edit 2: Using $u = i\,|\tilde{p}||\tilde{x}|\text{cos}(\theta)$ as suggested,
$$\Delta_F(\tilde{x}) = \frac{S_{D-2}}{(2\pi)^D}\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\pi} \text{d}u \text{d}\theta\,(\tan(\theta))^{D-2}\,\frac{u^{D-3}e^{u}}{(ir)^{D-2}}.\tag{5}$$

Am I missing some identity that involves gamma functions?

Comment: Doing the inverse Fourier transform is usually more familiar (from, e.g. the Born approximation for Coulomb scattering).  So you might want to try the opposite order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

1. Introduce a [Schwinger parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization) of $\frac{1}{\tilde{p}^2+m^2}$.
2. Do the $D$-dimensional Gaussian integral over $\tilde{p}$.
3. *Case $m=0$.* Make a substitution in the remaining integral over the Schwinger parameter, so that it turns into a well-known integral representation for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). (By the way, the $r$-dependence follows from dimensional analysis alone.)
4. *Case $m>0$.* Identify the remaining integral as an integral representation for the [modified Bessel function of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html).

Comment: This does, indeed, seem to solve the problem. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

$$
e^{ip\cdot x}= e^{i|p|r \cos \theta}
$$

Comment: My bad, I forgot I had done that already. Let me edit the question.

Comment: It does provide the what the OP did wrong, as he said.